# Space for a dropdown menu - HTML5/CSS3

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this dropdown menu:

[image]

The problem is that in mobile view, I have to reserve the space because when someone clicks the menu, if I don't reserve the space, the login and the li from the menu will merge

How can I solve this?

Thank you

Comment: give it a margin or padding? not much that i can tell you without seeing any codes

Comment: Here you can check the code http://2daw12.cesnuria.com/projecte/login

Answer (score 1):

In your live code, just remove the space. As the user doesn't look at the menu as well as type in the credentials at the same time!

You can make the drop-down push the contents in the mobile view. I am definitely sure it is not a good idea to have fixed headers for menus in mobile view. So, you may have a look at this **working demo** like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("header a").click(function () {
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
* {font-family: Segoe UI;}
body, ul, li {margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none;}
.wrap {width: 285px; margin: 15px auto; border: 5px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.75); box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px #000;}
header {background-color: #000; text-align: center;}
header a {color: #fff; text-decoration: none; display: block; padding: 5px;}
img {display: block; width: 100%;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <header>
    <a href="#">Click for Menu</a>
    <ul class="menu" style="display: none;">
      <li><a href="">Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Item 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Item 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Item 5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </header>
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/IJhK0iG.jpg?1" alt="Login" />      
</div>
```

Comment: Ok,  I can't remove the space

Comment: @mithrandir What happens?

Comment: Fixed! It seems there was a min-height that was creating that blank space.

Comment: Now I have this problem... When I hover the li from the menu in desktop view, the login form moves to the bottom a little bit http://2daw12.cesnuria.com/projecte/login

Comment: It seems that it's solved with a little bit of adjusting